# How to have Firefox torn tabs always restore down?

Tags: firefox, ux

When you tear a tab from the tab bar, then a new window is opened, but the new window always has the same 'state' (ie: if the original window was a maximized screen then the new window will be maximized window, if it was in the smaller state, lets call this the 'restored down' state, then same thing..).

What I want to know is this: **is there is some way to have torn tabs open new windows that are always in the 'restored down' state?** b/c I never want a new tab opened in the maximized state.